# airline reservation def help python

Tags: python, dictionary, definition

for my homework I am asked to create a airline reservation system. It asks if they would like to either create, cancel, display reservations, or exit the program. I am having trouble figuring out how to add the seats to the dictionary and still have them there when the code runs again. here is the basics of my code so far.

```
def reservation():

    print("Please choose an option: ")
    print("1. Reserve a Seat")
    print("2. Cancel a Reservation")
    print("3. Display Reservations")
    print("4. Exit")

    plane={}
    co=int(input("Enter a choice: "))

    #choose an option
    if co==1:
        seat=row+col
        
        #check if seat has been taken if not reserve
        if seat in plane:
            plane[seat]=name
            print("Seat row col has already been reserved by "+plane[key])
            reservation()
        else:
            plane[seat]=name
            print("Seat "+seat+" has been reserved for "+name)
            print (seat+" "+plane[seat])
            reservation()
            
                      
    elif co==2:
        row=input("Row (1-25): ")
        
        seat=row+col
        if seat in plane:
            del plane[seat]
            print("The reservation for seat "+seat+" has been cancelled.")
            input("Press enter to continue...")
        else:
            print("Seat "+seat+" is not currently reserved by anyone.")
            input("Press enter to continue...")
                   

    elif co==3:
        print("Reservations:")
        for key in plane:
            print(key+"\t"+plane[key])
    elif co==4:
        exit()
        
            
reservation()
```

Comment: You're probably going to need a loop of some kind

Answer (score 0):

In your program, I noticed that you attempt to continue calling your reservation function recursively in order to keep in acting like a loop.  As noted in the comments you probably would be better off utilizing a loop for this exercise.  Recursive function calls are good for things such as factorials, producing an exploded bill of materials, and such.

Also, I noticed that a few value assignments appeared to be backwards and actually would probably throw an error such as the following line of code.

```
if seat in plane:
    plane[seat]=name
```

The "name" variable doesn't appear to be defined yet so that probably was cause the program to halt.  With that in mind, I took a swing at doing some revisions and additions to the program in order for it to function in the spirit I believe you are after.  Following is the sample code.

```
def reservation():

    plane={}

    while True:
    
        #Choose an option
        print("Please choose an option: ")
        print("1. Reserve a Seat")
        print("2. Cancel a Reservation")
        print("3. Display Reservations")
        print("4. Save Reservations")
        print("5. Exit")
        
        co=int(input("Enter a choice: "))
    
        if co == 1:
            row  = int(input("Please enter a row: "))
            col  = int(input("Please enter a seat number (1 -6)"))
            
            # Since lists start at index 0, the formula will be adjusted to accomodate
            seat = (row - 1) * 6 + col - 1                      
        
            # Check if seat has been taken if not reserve
            if seat in plane:
                name = plane[seat]
                print("Seat", (seat + 1), "has already been reserved by " + plane[seat])
            else:
                name = input("Please enter your name ")
                plane[seat] = name
                print("Seat", (seat + 1), "has been reserved for", name)
                print ((seat + 1)," ", plane[seat])  
                                 
        elif co == 2:
            row = int(input("Row (1-25): "))
            col = int(input("Seat# (1 - 6): "))
        
            seat = (row - 1) * 6 + col - 1
            
            if seat in plane:
                del plane[seat]
                print("The reservation for seat", (seat + 1), "has been cancelled.")
                input("Press enter to continue...")
            else:
                print("Seat", (seat + 1), "is not currently reserved by anyone.")
                input("Press enter to continue...")
                   
        elif co == 3:
            print("Reservations:")
            for key in plane:
                print((key + 1), "\t", plane[key])
                
        elif co == 4:
            with open('plane.txt', 'w') as f:
                for line in plane:
                    record = plane[line] + " " + str(line + 1)
                    f.write(record)
            f.close()

        elif co == 5:
            break
        
reservation()
```

First off, I encapsulated the reservation logic within a "while" loop as suggested in the comments above.  That replaces the recursive calls and replaces the "exit()" call with a simple "break" call for option #4.  Next, since the plane seats are being treated like a list, I did some sleight of hand calculations to insure that the possible seat list would start at index "0".  I subtracted "1" where needed for deriving and index value and added "1" back in for viewing purposes.

Here is just a brief bit of text from my terminal testing out the program.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Reservations$ python3 Reservations.py 
Please choose an option: 
1. Reserve a Seat
2. Cancel a Reservation
3. Display Reservations
4. Save Reservations
5. Exit
Enter a choice: 1
Please enter a row: 4
Please enter a seat number (1 -6)2
Please enter your name Craig
Seat 20 has been reserved for Craig
20   Craig
Please choose an option: 
1. Reserve a Seat
2. Cancel a Reservation
3. Display Reservations
4. Save Reservations
5. Exit
Enter a choice: 4
Please choose an option: 
1. Reserve a Seat
2. Cancel a Reservation
3. Display Reservations
4. Save Reservations
5. Exit
Enter a choice: 5
```

Also, since you indicated that there was a need to save the reservations, I added a selection to the choices and a simple write to a text file for that.  It is over simplified and you probably can find better solutions for that.  Plus you will also probably want to add in some functionality to read the data back in.  That could be a further embellishment to be worked on.

Anyway, please examine this code.  Hopefully this will both clarify things for you plus give you ideas on how you might further embellish the functionality.

Regards.